# How to eliminate variables when they are to close together (i.e. closer than 200 ms -> delete the row )

Tags: r, heartrate

first post today.

Currently i am working on my research and i have to analyze heart rate data.
Now that i've completed most of my code i came to the discovery that the algorithm i am working in (RHRV) utilizes the occurences of the heartbeats, with matching seconds.

My simple txt file, in seconds, therefore looks like this (1 col, 433 rows): 
0.905
1.943
2.941
4.005
4.998
5.921

These are the heart beats and the second they occur.

My question now is: how do i delete the occurrences that are impossible like:
2 occurences/heartbeats happening faster that 0.2 seconds (200  ms)

Is there an easy way or function that allows me to alter the data?

Looking forward to your answers!

Cheers,

Sander

Comment: Your question is not entirely clear to me? If the data are 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.8, will you eliminate 0.4, 0.5, 0.6? Or will you keep 0.4 but eliminate 0.5 and 0.6? Or will you eliminate 0.8 as well, because it is within 0.2 from 0.6? Please give your desired output for a relevant set of input data.

Comment: hi! thanks for the feedback. Indeed i want to keep the first variable and delete all the closest occurences that arent humane possible. So in the case of 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.8 the 0.5 will be deleted and the rest stays since they are 0.2 apart.
In my file i have a few occurences of the following: 171.1156, 171.1345, 171.256, 171.309, 171.465, 171.4986, 171.986, 172.563

In this case i want to keep the first (171.1156) and delete everything in the 0.2 range, being: (171.1345, 171.256, 171.309)
Then it would jump to the next datapoint (171.465) and delete only:171.4986 since it is too close again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't think of a vectorised way to do this but this could work. Note that this will be expensive for long vectors as the expression `y <- c(y, x[i])` will keep reconstructing the vector `y`.

```
x <- c(171.1156, 171.1345, 171.256, 171.309, 171.465, 171.4986, 171.986, 172.563)
m <- 1
y <- numeric(0)
y[m] <- x[1]
for (i in 2:NROW(x)) {
    if (y[m] + 0.2 < x[i]) {
        m <- m + 1
        y <- c(y, x[i])
    }
}
y
# output
[1] 171.1156 171.4650 171.9860 172.5630
```

I iterate through the elements of `x` and every time I encounter a value that is more than 0.2 away from the latest accepted value in `y`, I update `y` with that `x[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
# create some random values
set.seed(3)
heartBeats <- sort(runif(10))

# which of them are reasonable?
keepThese <- heartBeats - lag(heartBeats) > 0.02
keepThese[is.na(keepThese)] <- TRUE # remove NAs

# and now subset the original vector
heartBeats[keepThese]
```